# Bash variable conflict

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am working on a linux bash script that is run and receives variables from from CSF Firewall.
The command that CSF Firewall issues is `system($config{RT_ACTION},$ip,$check,$block,$cnt,$mails);` where `$config{RT_ACTION}` is the path to my script.

`$mails=2013-04-16 11:57:14 1US8Fq-0001VC-Uu <= from@domain.com H=reverse.trace.of.ipaddress (server) [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:PORT I=[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:PORT P=esmtp S=5964 id=SOMEIDHERE$@com T="EMAILSUBJECT" from <from@domain.com> for to@domain.com`

The problem comes when I try to run this command to get from@domain.com.

```
DUMPED=$5
myvar=$(echo "$DUMPED" | awk '{print $5}')
```

If its not clear, $mails is passed to my script which translates to $5 and the information that I want to extract with awk is located in the 5th column which also translates to $5 so instead of $5 outputting from@domain.com it outputs the full content of $mails. What am I missing? Why won't awk set myvar to from@domain.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
DUMPED=$5
myvar=`echo $DUMPED | cut -d" " -f5`
```

or, using AWK:

```
DUMPED=$5
myvar=`echo $DUMPED | awk '{print $5}'`
```

It worked for me...

Comment: Actually, a pipe implies a subshell, as does your capturing expression with backticks. (Backticks are synonymous with `$()`.)

Comment: Thats true, its just that im used to call $( "subshell operator" and ` just "backtick operator"... :D

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully some of this is illustrative. Ultimately, I'm just showing that what you have already works, unless you're trying to define the variable *literally* with the dollar sign already in it.

```
$ # Define mails. Don't do $mails=something, that will fail.
$ mails='2013-04-16 11:57:14 1US8Fq-0001VC-Uu <= from@domain.com H=reverse.trace.of.ipaddress (server) [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:PORT I=[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:PORT P=esmtp S=5964 id=SOMEIDHERE$@com T="EMAILSUBJECT" from <from@domain.com> for to@domain.com'
$ # Direct the value of $mails to awk's standard input using a here string:
$ awk '{print $5}' <<< "$mails"
from@domain.com
$ # Direct the value of $mails to awk's standard input using echo and a pipe:
$ echo "$mails"| awk '{print $5}'
from@domain.com
$ # Assign the fifth word of "$mails" to the name "myvar" using read;
$ read _ _ _ _ myvar _ <<< "$mails"
$ echo "$myvar"
from@domain.com
```